# what solutions are available for running php after being forwarded to a node port on nginx

Tags: php, node.js, nginx

I am running nginx that listens to port 80 for php content. My nodejs server runs on port 3001. The problem I am having is that when I am sending the user to the nodejs server on port 3001, I also want to run php code. I have since learned that I cannot listen on nginx for port 3001 to run php code because nodejs is already using that port, and you cannot use the same port on both. My question is, what solution/s exist for this so that I can run php when I got to a webpage with port 3001 with nodejs.

I have tried using a reverse proxy, but my problem with that is when I am listening on port 80 for example on the homepage, where my port 3001 also exists (difference is xxyy.com vs xxyy.com:3001) I don't want to forward that info to port 3001 as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - you need a proxy server, but you must set up path-specific forwards instead of the entire port.  Note that

For PHP, there are several ways to run the PHP server, but this example uses PHP-FPM (see this [example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/)).  You could also set up another web server dedicated to PHP and use the same `upstream` syntax as the nodeJS service.

There are many ways to configure this (see documentation for the [location](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html) and [proxy](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) parameters), but here is an example nginx config using PHP-FPM via socket:

```
upstream nodeServer {
  server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

server {
  listen                *:80 default_server;
  server_name           _; # Listens for ALL hostnames

  index                 index.html;
  proxy_set_header      Host $host;
  proxy_http_version    1.1;
  proxy_set_header      Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header      Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_next_upstream   error timeout invalid_header;

  ## runs PHP pages with PHP-FPM
  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    ## fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; ## uncomment this to connect PHP-FPM via port
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock; ## uncomment this to connect PHP-FPM via socket
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  ## Forwards requests to the set of nodeJS servers defined in the "nodeServer" upstream
  location /js {
    proxy_pass          http://nodeServer;
  }

  ## serves static files
  location / {
    sendfile            on;
    try_files           $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank so much for all the notes. An issue that I am still dealing with is that I want to run php in the directory that I forward my user from. For example, forwarding from xx.com/yy/rr to xx.com:3001 for my node server seems to force all of my php that was in the original directory to not run because It says it has to be from port 3001, used by node. Does this account for that?

Comment: Yes - that's the idea behind using `location` to create route-specific forwards.  Node won't run PHP, and PHP won't run JS, so you need to forward requests for individual document types to the appropriate server (each on a different port/socket).  Obviously, this is most easily accomplished at a directory level, but it can be done on a per-document basis.

Comment: If I am forwarded to xx.com/yy/rr to xx.com:3001, how can I create a location specific section for both nodejs and php code to run on the per-document basis as you speak of, since being directory specific wouldn't work here?

Comment: Hi  @rickster26ter1 - sorry for the delay.  You can choose both *what* to forward and *where* to send it.  For instance, if you have `location /api` forwarding to `proxy_pass  http://nodeServer;` then requests for that path request the root of the `nodeServer` upstream.  You could also configure it like `proxy_pass  http://nodeServer/api` which would forward `/api` to the same path on `nodeServer`.

Comment: In addition to the many "how to" resources out there, I would check out the docs on these two options:
proxy_pass:  https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass
location:  https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location